# How to map two columns using another table in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table user_table like this:

user_table

```
user1, user2
123    122 
323    323
122    125
```

and I have a seperate table that maps users to zipcode.

user_zip

```
user zipcode
123    32456
323    12983
121    90878
...
```

Now I want to create a table like this:

```
user1, user2, user1_zip, user2_zip
```

I see that I can get a table like this from the following query:

```
select user1, user2, zipcode as user1_zip 
    from user_table as a inner join user_zip as b
    on a.user1 = b.user;
```

Not sure how to map user2 as well, and get one more column called user2_zip.

thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT ut.user1, uz1.zipcode AS zip1, ut.user2, uz2.zipcode AS zip2
FROM user_table AS ut
JOIN user_zip AS uz1 ON ut.user1 = uz1.user
JOIN user_zip AS uz2 ON ut.user2 = uz2.user
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join to the same table more than once:

```
select u.user1, u.user2, z1.zipcode [user1_zip], z2.zipcode [user2_zip]
from user_table u
join user_zip z1 on z1.user=u.user1
join user_zip z2 on z2.user=u.user2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
with temp as (
select user1 u
from user_table
union
select user2 u
from user_table
)

select u.*, uz.*
from temp
inner join user_zip uz on
temp.u = uz.user
```